# Assigning values to a 3D list does not work properly

Tags: c#, list

```
List<List<List<PointF>>> myList = new List<List<List<PointF>>>();
List<List<PointF>> subList = new List<List<PointF>>();
List<PointF> subSubList = new List<PointF>();
for(int x = 0; x<5; x++)
{
    for(int y = 0; y<15; y++)
    {
        for(int z = 0; z<15; z++)
        {
            subSubList.Add(new PointF(0, 0));
        }
        subList.Add(subSubList);
    }
    myList.Add(subList);
}
PointF first = new PointF(12, 12);
PointF second = new PointF(25, 14);
PointF third = new PointF(4, 44);

myList[0][8][10] = first;
myList[1][8][10] = second;
myList[2][8][10] = third;
```

When I debug each line, `first` gets correctly assigned to `myList[0][8][10]` but once it goes to the next line, the value of `myList[0][8][10]` changes to `PointF(25, 14)`.

By the end of the execution, the value at `myList[0][8][10]`, `myList[1][8][10]`, `myList[2][8][10]` are all `PointF(4, 44)`.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `myList`, `subList` and `subSubList` are assigned only once:

```
List<List<List<PointF>>> myList = new List<List<List<PointF>>>();
List<List<PointF>> subList = new List<List<PointF>>();
List<PointF> subSubList = new List<PointF>();
```

So everywhere else those variables refer to the same instances. Hence when you insert it:

```
subList.Add(subSubList);
...
myList.Add(subList);
```

You insert the same references multiple time in the same object.

That it:

- `myList[0] == myList[1] == .. myList[4] == subList`.
- `myList[_][0] == myList[_][1] == .. myList[_][14] == subSubList` whatever `_` is.

That's why `myList[a][b]` and `myList[c][d]` and `subSubList` are references to the same object whatever `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` are. So when you write `myList[2][8][10] = third;` it's the same as writing `subSubList[10] == third;` and reading `myList[a][b][10]` is the same as reading `subSubList[10]`.

To make it work you should instantiate new objects after insertions:

```
subList.Add(subSubList);
subSubList = new List<PointF>();
```

and

```
myList.Add(subList);
subList = new List<List<PointF>>();
```